# Where is a file mounted?

Tags: c++, linux, mount

Given a path to a file or directory, how can I determine the mount point for that file? For example, if `/tmp` is mounted as a `tmpfs` filesystem then given the file name `/tmp/foo/bar` I want to know that it's stored on a `tmpfs` rooted at `/tmp`.

This will be in C++ and I'd like to avoid invoking external commands via `system()`. The code should be robust--not necessarily against deliberate tampering but definitely in the face of nested mountpoints, symlinks, etc.

I haven't been able to find a simple system call to do this. It looks like I'll have to write the check myself. Here's a rough outline of what I'm planning.

1. Canonicalize the file name a la the `readlink` shell command. **How?**
2. Read `/etc/mtab` with `getmntent()` & co.
3. Determine the corresponding mount entry for the file. **How?**

For #1 is there a simple system call or do I need to read each directory component of the path and resolve them with `readlink(2)` if they are symlinks? And handle `.` and `..` myself? Seems like a pain.

For #3 I've got various ideas on how to do this. Not sure which is best.

1. `open()` the file, its parent, its parent's parent, etc. using `openat(fd, "..")` until I reach one of the `/etc/mtab` entries. (**How do I know when I do? `fstat()` them and compare the inode numbers?**)
2. Find the longest directory name in the mount table which is a substring of my file name.

I'm leaning towards the first option but before I code it all up I want to make sure I'm not overlooking anything--ideally a built-in function that does this already!

Comment: Why vote to close this? It is a good question.

Comment: Whoever voted to close it probably just read the title and/or the first two lines. This is clearly an appropriate (and interesting) question.

Comment: See also [Python version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260116/find-size-and-free-space-of-the-filesystem-containing-a-given-file) and a [shell command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274354/how-to-find-out-mount-partition-a-directory-or-file-is-on-linux-server).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is what I've come up with. It turns out there's usually no need to iterate through the parent directories. All you have to do is get the file's device number and then find the corresponding mount entry with the same device number.

```
struct mntent *mountpoint(char *filename, struct mntent *mnt, char *buf, size_t buflen)
{
    struct stat s;
    FILE *      fp;
    dev_t       dev;

    if (stat(filename, &s) != 0) {
        return NULL;
    }

    dev = s.st_dev;

    if ((fp = setmntent("/proc/mounts", "r")) == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    while (getmntent_r(fp, mnt, buf, buflen)) {
        if (stat(mnt->mnt_dir, &s) != 0) {
            continue;
        }

        if (s.st_dev == dev) {
            endmntent(fp);
            return mnt;
        }
    }

    endmntent(fp);

    // Should never reach here.
    errno = EINVAL;
    return NULL;
}
```

Thanks to @RichardPennington for the heads up on `realpath()`, and on comparing device numbers instead of inode numbers.

Comment: Nice. Much better than mine since you get all the information you need.

Comment: You might want to use /proc/mounts instead of /etc/mtab - /etc/mtab is maintained by the mount command and could be fudged with, whereas /proc/mounts is a representation of the mount table itself.

BSD users should use getmntinfo()

Comment: That should even work on device special files, without the need for the special-case at the end (`stat.st_dev` is *always* the ID of the device containing the file, even for device special files).

Comment: Since devices can be mounted more than once, isn't there some additional checking needed to check that you have the right mount of the device?

Answer (score 4):

You could start with realpath and work your way up checking each directory with stat to see if it on the same device. It does seem like there should be a simpler way.

---

Edit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *p;
    char path[PATH_MAX];
    struct stat buf;
    dev_t dev;

    if (realpath(argv[1], path) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't find %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (stat(path, &buf) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't statind %s\n", path);
    exit(1);
    }

    dev = buf.st_dev;
    while((p = strrchr(path, '/'))) {
        *p = '\0';
        stat(path, &buf);
        if (buf.st_dev != dev) {
            printf("mount point = %s\n", path);
            exit(0);
        }
   }
    printf("mount point = /\n");
}
```

Thanksd for the distraction ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on OSX, which does not provide the mntent functions. In C++:

```
struct stat fileStat;
int result = stat(path, &fileStat);
if (result != 0) {
    // handle error
}    

struct statfs* mounts;
int numMounts = getmntinfo(&mounts, MNT_WAIT);
if (numMounts == 0) {
    // handle error
}    

for (int i = 0; i < numMounts; i++) {
    if (fileStat.st_dev == mounts[i].f_fsid.val[0])
        // mounts[i].f_mntonname is the mount path
}
```

Comment: Is your OSX(C++) any kind of linux or not? `getmntinfo` sounds like FreeBSD/OSX(C++) library call, but not linux or POSIX.

Comment: The question was about linux.

Comment: Yes, I did indicate that it's OSX, which is often easily ported to/from Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to read in `/etc/mtab`, parse out all the locations where something is already mounted, and see if any of your files in question are located in any of those locations (or their sub-directories).  You shouldn't need any special system functions for this, if you have the mount points and file paths as strings then you can process them using normal string processing functions.

Obviously, symlinks can throw a wrench into this whole process.  Any file path that includes a symlink will have to be converted into its "actual" path before processing it.  <strike>Hopefully there's a way to do this without individually checking a file and each of its parents, but you can always brute-force it if you must.</strike>  You'll probably want to use [`realpath`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/realpath.html) to remove symlinks.