# How to find out mount/partition a directory or file is on? (Linux Server)

Tags: linux, file, directory, mount, disk-partitioning

Is there a Linux command to easily find out which partition/mount a directory or file is on?

(This is probably a RTM question, and I feel guilty for asking it, but somehow, I can't find a good answer on google just yet..)

Comment: @TylerCollier google sent me here... so please stop these dramass!

Comment: @ErdemEce that's my point. ina mentioned RTFM, but Google (and what it links to) counts as a manual now :-)

Comment: UNIX exchange version: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11311/how-do-i-find-on-which-physical-device-a-folder-is-located

Comment: getting the mount for a directory to troubleshoot a low diskspace error in order to restart a jenkins node that runs the CI loop for your team's web stack seems awfully like a tool used primarily in programming...

Comment: @worc Agree. I have exactly the same issue and got my solution here as the accepted answer below.

Comment: The various program ways to achieve this are described well at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313502/103306

Answer (score 266, accepted):

```
df -P file/goes/here | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f 1
```

Comment: I get following when I run above command. /dev/mapper/vg_mymachine-lv. how do I know on which primary partition it belongs too. i.e. sda1, sda2, hda1 etc?

Comment: By looking at your LVM configuration.

Comment: Great command! I wouldn't use the piping though. Getting to know information about space (at the same time you get to know about which partition your folder/file is on) is quite amusing as well :)

Comment: Very nice; here's the same thing done with awk:
`df -P /home | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1}'`

Comment: Gotta admit, I really dislike pure command answers, can you make an edit and explain the options/params used?

Comment: to check websites which are located on /var/www/html  `df -P /var/www/html | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f 1`