# Python split and merge the line

Tags: python

```
df = subprocess.Popen(["df", options.partname], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = df.communicate()[0]
print output
```

gives the following:

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/sys-scratch
                     1446412616 847216452 524555652  62% /scratch
```

In some cases (machines),

```
output.split("\n")[1]
```

gives me

```
/dev/mapper/sys-scratch
```

where as I want

```
/dev/mapper/sys-scratch 1446412616 847216452 524555652  62% /scratch  # in one line
```

I am using the values in the output like this :

```
device, size, used, available, percent, mountpoint = output.split("\n")[1].split()
```

For some machines, this fails because `output.split("\n")[1]` only has a single value. How can I fix this ?

Comment: It looks like a newline is inserted to fit the longer filesystem name.

Comment: Which information do you need, exactly? `df` isn't designed for scripted parsing; there are better ways to get disk information.

Comment: The **other** answers in [Find size and free space of the filesystem containing a given file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4260116) are actually better than using `df`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific case, you can re-join the last 2 lines:

```
df = subprocess.Popen(["df", options.partname], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = df.communicate()[0]
output = ' '.join(output.splitlines()[1:])
device, size, used, available, percent, mountpoint = output.split()
```