# How to get the filesystem of a directory or drive?

Tags: python, filesystems

How do I determine if a given path or drive is formatted to EXT4, EXT3, EXT2, FAT32, NTFS or some such, in Python?

Comment: Related: [Find size and free space of the filesystem containing a given file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4260116/279627)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[psutil](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/) is a cross-platform package which can [identify partition types](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.disk_partitions):

```
>>> psutil.disk_partitions()
[sdiskpart(device='/dev/sda1', mountpoint='/', fstype='ext4', opts='rw,nosuid'),
 sdiskpart(device='/dev/sda2', mountpoint='/home', fstype='ext4', opts='rw')]
```

Warning: On linux, the fstype may be reported as `ext4` or `ntfs`, but on Windows, the fstype is limited to `"removable", "fixed", "remote", "cdrom", "unmounted" or "ramdisk"`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. If there were a way to find out the file system of a specific directory, that would be a great addition to your answer. This helps anyhow, though.

Comment: On Linux, you could try parsing the output of `df -TP path`, but doing so could be very tricky since the device name and mount point can contain
spaces.

Comment: Looks like on you can now get the actual fstype on Windows, so your previous warning is now 'invalid'. I can confirm it works, but also see this commit message for psutil: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/209#issuecomment-44019539

Answer (score 1):

Although it has been a while since the question and answer were posted, I just want to add a little function that you can use to actually find the file system of a given path. The answer extends [unutbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23081538).
The answer is also quite useful for macOS users, where it is not possible to print the file system with `df -T` (also at my machine `df --print-type` did also not work). See the [man page](https://ss64.com/osx/df.html) for more information (it suggests using the `lsvfs` command to display the available file systems).

```py
import psutil
import os

def extract_fstype(path_=os.getcwd()):
    """Extracts the file system type of a given path by finding the mountpoint of the path."""
    for i in psutil.disk_partitions(all=True):
        if path_.startswith(i.mountpoint):
            
            if i.mountpoint == '/':  # root directory will always be found
                # print(i.mountpoint, i.fstype, 'last resort')  # verbose
                last_resort = i.fstype
                continue
            
            # print(i.mountpoint, i.fstype, 'return')  # verbose
            return i.fstype

    return last_resort
```

(tested on macOS and linux)