# numpy.memmap: bogus memory allocation

Tags: python, linux, numpy, memory-mapped-files, sparse-file

I have a `python3` script that operates with `numpy.memmap` arrays. It writes an array to newly generated temporary file that is located in `/tmp`:

```
import numpy, tempfile

size = 2 ** 37 * 10
tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w+')
array = numpy.memmap(tmp.name, dtype = 'i8', mode = 'w+', shape = size)
array[0] = 666
array[size-1] = 777
del array
array2 = numpy.memmap(tmp.name, dtype = 'i8', mode = 'r+', shape = size)
print('File: {}. Array size: {}. First cell value: {}. Last cell value: {}'.\
      format(tmp.name, len(array2), array2[0], array2[size-1]))
while True:
    pass
```

The size of the HDD is only 250G. Nevertheless, it can somehow generate 10T large files in `/tmp`, and the corresponding array still seems to be accessible. The output of the script is following:

```
File: /tmp/tmptjfwy8nr. Array size: 1374389534720. First cell value: 666. Last cell value: 777
```

The file really exists and is displayed as being 10T large:

```
$ ls -l /tmp/tmptjfwy8nr
-rw------- 1 user user 10995116277760 Dec  1 15:50 /tmp/tmptjfwy8nr
```

However, the whole size of `/tmp` is much smaller:

```
$ df -h /tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       235G  5.3G  218G   3% /
```

The process also is pretending to use 10T virtual memory, which is also not possible. The output of `top` command:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND 
31622 user      20   0 10.000t  16592   4600 R 100.0  0.0   0:45.63 python3
```

As far as I understand, this means that during the call of `numpy.memmap` the needed memory for the whole array is not allocated and therefore displayed file size is bogus. This in turn means that when I start to gradually fill the whole array with my data, at some point my program will crash or my data will be corrupted.

Indeed, if I introduce the following in my code:

```
for i in range(size):
    array[i] = i
```

I get the error after a while:

```
Bus error (core dumped)
```

**Therefore, the question:** how to check at the beginning, if there is really enough memory for the data and then indeed reserve the space for the whole array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### There's nothing 'bogus' about the fact that you are generating 10 TB files

You are asking for arrays of size

> 2 ** 37 * 10 = 1374389534720 elements

A dtype of `'i8'` means an 8 byte (64 bit) integer, therefore your final array will have a size of

> 1374389534720 * 8 = 10995116277760 bytes

or

> 10995116277760 / 1E12 = 10.99511627776 TB

---

#### If you only have 250 GB of free disk space then how are you able to create a "10 TB" file?

Assuming that you are using a reasonably modern filesystem, your OS will be capable of generating almost arbitrarily large [sparse files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file), regardless of whether or not you actually have enough physical disk space to back them.

For example, on my Linux machine I'm allowed to do something like this:

```sh
# I only have about 50GB of free space...
~$ df -h /
Filesystem     Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1      ext4  459G  383G   53G  88% /

~$ dd if=/dev/zero of=sparsefile bs=1 count=0 seek=10T
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0.000236933 s, 0.0 kB/s

# ...but I can still generate a sparse file that reports its size as 10 TB
~$ ls -lah sparsefile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alistair alistair 10T Dec  1 21:17 sparsefile

# however, this file uses zero bytes of "actual" disk space
~$ du -h sparsefile
0       sparsefile
```

Try calling `du -h` on your `np.memmap` file after it has been initialized to see how much actual disk space it uses.

As you start actually writing data to your `np.memmap` file, everything will be OK until you exceed the physical capacity of your storage, at which point the process will terminate with a `Bus error`. This means that if you needed to write < 250GB of data to your `np.memmap` array then there might be no problem (in practice this would probably also depend on where you are writing within the array, and on whether it is row or column major).

---

#### How is it possible for a process to use 10 TB of virtual memory?

When you create a [memory map](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), the kernel allocates a new block of addresses within the virtual address space of the calling process and maps them to a file on your disk. The amount of virtual memory that your Python process is using will therefore increase by the size of the file that has just been created. Since the file can also be sparse, then not only can the virtual memory exceed the total amount of RAM available, but it can also exceed the total physical disk space on your machine.

---

#### How can you check whether you have enough disk space to store the full `np.memmap` array?

I'm assuming that you want to do this programmatically in Python.

1. Get the amount of free disk space available. There are various methods given in the answers to [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4260116/1461210). One option is [`os.statvfs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.statvfs):

   ```
   import os

   def get_free_bytes(path='/'):
       st = os.statvfs(path)
       return st.f_bavail * st.f_bsize

   print(get_free_bytes())
   # 56224485376
   ```
2. Work out the size of your array in bytes:

   ```
   import numpy as np

   def check_asize_bytes(shape, dtype):
       return np.prod(shape) * np.dtype(dtype).itemsize

   print(check_asize_bytes((2 ** 37 * 10,), 'i8'))
   # 10995116277760
   ```
3. Check whether 2. > 1.

---

#### *Update:* Is there a 'safe' way to allocate an `np.memmap` file, which guarantees that sufficient disk space is reserved to store the full array?

One possibility might be to use [`fallocate`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fallocate) to pre-allocate the disk space, e.g.:

```
~$ fallocate -l 1G bigfile

~$ du -h bigfile
1.1G    bigfile
```

You could call this from Python, for example using [`subprocess.check_call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call):

```
import subprocess

def fallocate(fname, length):
    return subprocess.check_call(['fallocate', '-l', str(length), fname])

def safe_memmap_alloc(fname, dtype, shape, *args, **kwargs):
    nbytes = np.prod(shape) * np.dtype(dtype).itemsize
    fallocate(fname, nbytes)
    return np.memmap(fname, dtype, *args, shape=shape, **kwargs)

mmap = safe_memmap_alloc('test.mmap', np.int64, (1024, 1024))

print(mmap.nbytes / 1E6)
# 8.388608

print(subprocess.check_output(['du', '-h', 'test.mmap']))
# 8.0M    test.mmap
```

I'm not aware of a platform-independent way to do this using the standard library, but there is a [`fallocate` Python module on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fallocate/1.0.1) that should work for any Posix-based OS.

Comment: This is very good and detailed answer. However, as far as I understood, there is no way to make it safe. What if some other process creates a large file *after* I had checked the available space? Is there a way to generate normal file instead of a sparse one and *reserve* the required space in advance?

Comment: Good solution, though with one little flaw: the actual size of `memmap` file is somewhat bigger than the total size of array elements, due to the need to store `dtype` and some other metadata. Occasionally this overhead can also lead to `Bus error`. It would be good to find a way to get in advance the full file size.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to. If you're creating your arrays using `np.memmap` then the files should not contain any header information - they are exactly the same size as you would predict based on the dimensions of the array and the item size. Could you give an example? Perhaps there is some confusion over units - an "SI" terabyte is 1E12 bytes, whereas a binary ["tebibyte"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terabyte) is 2^40 bytes. `fallocate` can use either convention `10TB` means 1E12 bytes, whereas `10TiB` means 2**40 bytes.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong: the file size exactly matches the size of data. The confusion was actually with `pickle` dumps of `numpy` arrays.

Comment: Ah OK. I would suggest you avoid using `pickle` for numpy arrays - it's an extremely inefficient way to store numerical data. It's much better to use `np.save`/`np.savez`, or `ndarray.tofile` if you just want a raw binary file with no headers. HDF5 might also make sense for large datasets.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the answer of @ali_m I finally came to this solution:

```
# must be called with the argumant marking array size in GB
import sys, numpy, tempfile, subprocess

size = (2 ** 27) * int(sys.argv[1])
tmp_primary = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w+')
array = numpy.memmap(tmp_primary.name, dtype = 'i8', mode = 'w+', shape = size)
tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w+')
check = subprocess.Popen(['cp', '--sparse=never', tmp_primary.name, tmp.name])
stdout, stderr = check.communicate()
if stderr:
    sys.stderr.write(stderr.decode('utf-8'))
    sys.exit(1)
del array
tmp_primary.close()
array = numpy.memmap(tmp.name, dtype = 'i8', mode = 'r+', shape = size)
array[0] = 666
array[size-1] = 777
print('File: {}. Array size: {}. First cell value: {}. Last cell value: {}'.\
      format(tmp.name, len(array), array[0], array[size-1]))
while True:
    pass
```

The idea is to copy initially generated sparse file to a new normal one. For this `cp` with the option `--sparse=never` is employed.

When the script is called with a manageable size parameter (say, 1 GB) the array is getting mapped to a non-sparse file. This is confirmed by the output of `du -h` command, which now shows ~1 GB size. If the memory is not enough, the scripts exits with the error:

```
cp: ‘/tmp/tmps_thxud2’: write failed: No space left on device
```

Comment: `cp --sparse-never` will be *very* slow compared to `fallocate` for large sparse files, since it will write zero bytes for the entire file. `fallocate` is almost instantaneous, since it just allocates blocks without zeroing them.