# load np.memmap without knowing shape

Tags: python, numpy, memory-mapped-files, joblib

Is it possible to load a `numpy.memmap` without knowing the shape and still recover the shape of the data?

```
data = np.arange(12, dtype='float32')
data.resize((3,4))
fp = np.memmap(filename, dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(3,4))
fp[:] = data[:]
del fp
newfp = np.memmap(filename, dtype='float32', mode='r', shape=(3,4))
```

In the last line, I want to be able not to specify the shape and still get the variable `newfp` to have the shape `(3,4)`, just like it would happen with `joblib.load`. Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not unless that information has been explicitly stored in the file somewhere. As far as [`np.memmap`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) is concerned, the file is just a flat buffer.

I would recommend using [`np.save`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) to persist numpy arrays, since this also preserves the metadata specifying their dimensions, dtypes etc. You can also load an `.npy` file as a memmap by passing the `memmap_mode=` parameter to [`np.load`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.load.html).

[`joblib.dump`](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/generated/joblib.dump.html) uses a combination of pickling to store generic Python objects and `np.save` to store numpy arrays.

---

To initialize an empty memory-mapped array backed by a `.npy` file you can use `numpy.lib.format.open_memmap`:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.format import open_memmap

# initialize an empty 10TB memory-mapped array
x = open_memmap('/tmp/bigarray.npy', mode='w+', dtype=np.ubyte, shape=(10**13,))
```

You might be surprised by the fact that this succeeds *even if the array is larger than the total available disk space* (my laptop only has a 500GB SSD, but I just created a 10TB memmap). This is possible because the file that's created is [sparse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34029352/1461210).

Credit for discovering `open_memmap` should go to [kiyo's previous answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4620395/1461210).

Comment: The thing is I am dealing with very big data and `memmap` avoids filling all the RAM. I am also using it with `joblib.Parallel` to parallely write to disk.

Comment: As I said, you can also open an `.npy` file as a memory-mapped array by passing the `memmap_mode=` parameter to `np.load`. Another option would be to use a combination of `joblib.dump` and `joblib.load` with the `memmap_mode=` parameter, which uses `np.save` and `np.load` under the hood.

Comment: Suppose I need to initialize 100 GB of data, and I only have 32 GB of RAM. In that situation, I am forced to use `memmap` in write mode. Now, `np.load` doesn't work in such case: I have to read it again using `memmap` in read mode. The question is, how to do this without knowing the shape of the data, and still get the shapes right.

Comment: I see - you should include this information in your question. In that case you can use `numpy.lib.format.open_memmap` to initialize an empty memory-mapped array backed by a `.npy` file (see [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4335289/1461210)).

Comment: @ali_m So why `np.memmap` exists? I still can't understand why one should prefer `np.memmap` over `np.load`.

Comment: One difference is that `np.load` can only be used to load an existing file, whereas `np.memmap` (and `open_memmap)` can create new files. `np.memmap` is more low-level, in that it just maps a flat buffer into memory. `np.load` and `open_memmap` operate on `.npy` files that have headers describing the shape and dtype of the elements, which may or may not be necessary depending on your use-case.

Comment: `np.memmap` is more lightweight and much faster than `np.load` if you open mmap very frequently, you may prefer `np.memmap` if you [reconstruct the memory map with each read / write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132940/numpy-memmap-memory-usage-want-to-iterate-once#:~:text=reconstruct%20the%20memory%20map%20with%20each%20read%20/%20write) for a large data file

Answer (score 2):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36749821/3919475) from @ali_m is perfectly valid. I would like to mention my personal preference, in case it helps anyone. I always begin my memmap arrays with the shape as the first 2 elements. Doing this is as simple as:

```
# Writing the memmap array
fp = np.memmap(filename, dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(3,4))
fp[:] = data[:]
fp = np.memmap(filename, dtype='float32', mode='r+', shape=(14,))
fp[2:] = fp[:-2]
fp[:2] = [3, 4]
del fp
```

Or simpler still:

```
# Writing the memmap array
fp = np.memmap(filename, dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(14,))
fp[2:] = data[:]
fp[:2] = [3, 4]
del fp
```

Then you can easily read the array as:

```
#reading the memmap array
newfp = np.memmap(filename, dtype='float32', mode='r')
row_size, col_size = newfp[0:2]
newfp = newfp[2:].reshape((row_size, col_size))
```

Comment: That's fine so long as you only ever use 2D arrays with a fixed dtype (also you really ought to be storing array dimensions as integers rather than floats). The main advantage to using `np.save` or `numpy.lib.format.open_memmap` is that these automatically store metadata specifying the shape and the dtype of the array.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `numpy.memmap` is `tifffile.memmap`:

```
from tifffile import memmap
newArray = memmap("name", shape=(3,3), dtype='uint8')
newArray[1,1] = 11
del(newArray)
```

`newArray` file is created having values:

```
0  0  0
0  11 0
0  0  0
```

Now lets read it back:

```
array = memmap("name", dtype='uint8')
print(array.shape) # prints (3,3)
print(array)
```

prints:

```
0  0  0
0  11 0
0  0  0
```