# Get a list of all mounted file systems in Linux with python

Tags: python, json, linux, shell, automation

I am planning to automate a process of cleaning file systems in Linux using a set of scripts in Shell, Python and I'll create a simple dashboard using Node.js to allow a more visual approach.

I have a script in Shell which already cleans a file system in a specific server - but I have to login and then issue this command. Now I am proceeding with a dashboard in HTML/CSS/JS to visualize all servers which are having space problems.

My idea is: create a Python scrip to login and get a list of filesystems and its usage and update a single JSON file, then, my dashboard uses this JSON to feed the screen.

My question is how to get the list of file system in Linux and its usage?

Comment: You want to login using SSH or you want to login into the webapp ?

Comment: Try the command `df`.

Comment: You can use paramiko client to log in to a remote ssh and run "df" command inside to get information about all partitions

Comment: Please take a look to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260116/find-size-and-free-space-of-the-filesystem-containing-a-given-file).

Comment: @DanIonescu, who will perform this ssh will be a python script, I'll run this command from my server and the Python script will perform this SSH connection to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remote connect to a ssh and retrive a list with the filesystems and usage you can use paramiko SSH client and df command like this:

To install paramiko using pip issue:

```
sudo pip install paramiko
```

The regex module should be default installed

```
import paramiko, re

server = "your_server_ip_or_name"
username = "your_ssh_user"
password = "your_ssh_password"

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=password)
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command("df")

filesystems = []
for line in ssh_stdout.readlines()[1:]:
    line = re.sub('\s+', ' ', line).strip()
    parameters = line.split(' ')
    usage_percent =  re.findall(r'\d+', parameters[4])
    filesystems.append({'name' : parameters[0], 'usage' : usage_percent[0]})

print filesystems
```

It will result in a list of dictionaries containing keys name, and usage like in this example:

```
[{'usage': u'17%', 'name': u'/dev/root'}, {'usage': u'0%', 'name': u'devtmpfs'}, {'usage': u'0%', 'name': u'tmpfs'}, {'usage': u'9%', 'name': u'tmpfs'}, {'usage': u'1%', 'name': u'tmpfs'}, {'usage': u'0%', 'name': u'tmpfs'}, {'usage': u'31%', 'name': u'/dev/mmcblk0p6'}, {'usage': u'0%', 'name': u'tmpfs'}]
```

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score -1):

You can use command

`df`

Provides an option to display sizes in Human Readable formats  (e.g., 1K 1M 1G) by using ‘-h’.This is the most common command but
you can also check `du` and `di`. `di` in fact provides even more info than `df`.

Comment: I know the command, I need to know how to execute it with Python and receive a list to iterate over it.

Comment: Ok, Glad to see you got what you wanted above. You can also consider fabric if you want to connect and get info from multiple nodes http://www.fabfile.org/

Comment: Thank you A D. I will check it out!