# How do I query “Size on disk” file information using a python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to reproduce behaviour exhibited in the Windows Explorer -> Properties dialog -> General property page for any given file. Specifically I want to reproduce the exact value of the "Size on disk"   **using a python**
[FOTO2](https://ibb.co/Hp1htQT)
Help please!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find size and free space of the filesystem containing a given file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260116/find-size-and-free-space-of-the-filesystem-containing-a-given-file)

Comment: [uncompressed files] A possible workaround is calculate the "Size on disk" via file size retrieved by GetFileSizeEx. For example, if the cluster size is 4096. The file size is 14,638 bytes. The number of clusters this file uses can be figured using this formula: File Size / Cluster Size, rounded up. We get 4 here so the Size on disk is 4*4096=16,384 bytes.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT sorry, I attached not quite the right photo, look at "photo2"

Comment: @DavidValters It seems the `Size on disk` is smaller that `Size` from *"photo2"*. Is it compressed file?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT No, this file is still being downloaded via torrent