# Given the directory name, how to find the Filesystem on which it resides in C?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, directory, mount

For example, a sample `df` command output is

```
Filesystem    MB blocks      Free %Used    Iused %Iused Mounted on
/dev/hd4         512.00    322.96   37%     4842     7% /
/dev/hd2        4096.00    717.96   83%    68173    29% /usr
/dev/hd9var     1024.00    670.96   35%     6385     4% /var
/dev/hd3        5120.00      0.39  100%      158    10% /tmp
```

Now if I specify something like `/tmp/dummy.txt` I should be able to get `/dev/hd3` or just `hd3`.

**EDIT** : Thanks torek for the answer. But probing the `/proc` would become very tedious. Can anyone suggest me some system calls which can do the same internally?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337139/where-is-a-file-mounted).

Comment: @Banthar The answers in that question are giving the mount points and not the filesystem name as `df` does :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df `pwd`
```

...Super simple, works, and also tells you how much space is there...

```
[stackuser@rhel62 ~]$ pwd
/home/stackuser
[stackuser@rhel62 ~]$ df `pwd`
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda7            250056240 196130640  41223408  83% /
[stackuser@rhel62 ~]$ cd isos
[stackuser@rhel62 isos]$ pwd
/home/stackuser/isos
[stackuser@rhel62 isos]$ df `pwd`
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5            103216920  90417960  11750704  89% /mnt/sda5
[stackuser@rhel62 isos]$ df $(pwd)
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5            103216920  90417960  11750704  89% /mnt/sda5
```

...which is the likely cause of the mount point query in the first place.

Note those are backticks, and the alternate (modern) method, providing further control over slashes and expansion is `df $(pwd)`.  Tested and traverses symlinks correctly on `bash`, `dash`, `busybox`, `zsh`.  Note that `tcsh` won't like the `$(...)`, so stick to the older backtick style in csh-variants.

There are also extra switches in `pwd` and `df` for further enjoyment.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, use `/proc/<pid>/mounts` to access a list of mount points for a given `pid`, or `/proc/self/mounts` (with the literal word `self`) to refer to yourself.  (`cat` the `/proc/self/mount*` files to see what they look like.)

Then, for each file system, you can do a `statfs()` call and compare `f_fsid` the `f_fsid` field to the result from an earlier `statfs()` on the path in question.  Once the `fsid's` match, you have found the appropriate mounted file system and can use the other data from `/proc/self/mounts`.  (However, see `statfs(2)` for restrictions on doing anything useful with `f_fsid`.)