# Detecting that a mount point has noexec set before calling exec() on a file?

Tags: c, linux, mount, stat, fcntl

My program calls exec() on a binary that has been written to a directory specified by the user. If the directory resides in a tree mounted with "noexec", the exec() fails with EACCES.

Instead of failing the exec(), I would like to be able to figure out if a directory was mounted with noexec, but none of fcntl(), stat() or mount() return this info (from reading the manpages). Looking at the kernel source for the exec system call, it looks like this info is stored in the metadata of the inode, and I don't see this info being returned from any system call.

```
 673     struct nameidata nd;
 (..)
 677     err = path_lookup_open(AT_FDCWD, name, LOOKUP_FOLLOW, &nd, FMODE_READ|FMODE_EXEC);
 678     file = ERR_PTR(err);
 (..)
 682         file = ERR_PTR(-EACCES);
 683         if (!(nd.mnt->mnt_flags & MNT_NOEXEC) &&
 684             S_ISREG(inode->i_mode)) {
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with checking if exec fails with EACCES?

Comment: Indeed, attempting to check if an operation will fail before performing it, instead of trying it and checking for failure, is **almost always a bug**.

Comment: @JesusRamos: Nothing wrong with that, I want to flag an error earlier.

Comment: @R..: *In general* it would be a bad idea, but in my program it won't matter, and will make it easier for the user.

Comment: @Mayank How does it make it easier or better for the user?
`if (can_exec) report_err(); else exec();`
vs
`if (exec) report_err();`
Which one seems "easier" to you.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that failure is the exception, not the norm. So it's better to try and fail than to check each time before you try (at least in this case). And to elaborate more on R's point remember that EACCESS is not the only reason that an exec can fail so you would need even more checks and it's not always fool proof (OS can OOM and there's no easy way to check for that).

Comment: @JesusRamos: My app sets the directory up from one interactive process and execs a binary from another noninteractive process. Where I do the error check matters. That's why it's "easier".

Comment: @Mayank So you want to check for every possible error? You can use basic IPC to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [statvfs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fstatvfs.3.html)()

```
struct statvfs st;
inr rc = statvfs("/mnt/foo", &st);
if (rc == -1)
   error();
if (st.f_flag & ST_NOEXEC) {
 //no exec flags was set
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the job, but is defeated if "/mnt/foo/bar" is passed as an argument to statvfs. f_flags doesn't have ST_NOEXEC set, only /mnt/foo does.

Comment: I need to make my code work on Mac too so looking at /proc as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337139/where-is-a-file-mounted?rq=1 isn't an option.

Comment: Bah, I don't like the other option of using realpath() + stat() to compare devices either. Never mind.

Comment: @Mayank I cannot reproduce that here. You should be able to give any path below the mount point as an argument and receive the correct mount flags for that file system.

Comment: I can see the difference pretty consistently on kernel 2.6.35.8.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider reading `/proc/mounts` then determining which file system your program binary resides on, perhaps using [statfs(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fstatfs.2.html) and/or [realpath(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html)?

But you always should care about, and handle, the failure of [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and related `exec` functions, which can fail for a variety of reasons.

<sup>There are many ways `execve` can fail, and some of them are not easily reproducible; likewise for the failure of `fork` or any other syscall.</sup>

I would either leave and report the `EACCESS` error (of `execve`), or, if you absolutely want to catch & explain more the `noexec` mount option, do the more complex thing (`statfs` and/or `realpath` and scanning of `/proc/mounts` or `/proc/self/mounts`) after such an `EACCESS`  failure.

There is no much point in testing a binary path before `execve`-ing it ... just report the error after...